# How to return an array in .toString method

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, return

How can I return an array in this `.toString` method of my `Shelf` class?

```
public class Book 
{
    int wys, szer;
    String imie, tytul;

public Book(int wys, int szer, String imie, String tytul)
    {
        this.wys = wys;
        this.szer = szer;
        this.imie = imie;
        this.tytul = tytul;
    }

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return imie;
}

}





public class Shelf
{


int wys;
    private Book book[] = new Book[20];


public Shelf(Book[] ks, int j)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ks.length - 1; i++)
    {

        this.book[i] = ks[i];

    }
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    for (int i=0;i<book.length;i++)
    {
    return book[i].toString();
    }

}


}
```

> Main class

```
public class Test
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Book ks[]={ 
            new Book (13,2, "Rhonda Byrne", "Sekret"), 
            new Book(12, 1, "Graham Greene", "Monsignore Kichote"),
            new Book(19, 3, "Hugo Steinhaus", "Slownik racjonalny"),
            new Book(10, 4, "RE.M. Remarque", "Trzej towarzysze"), 
            new Book(13, 3, "A.A. Milne", "Kubus Puchatek"),
            new Book(11, 4, "Paulo Coelho", "El Aquimista"), 
            new Book(13, 5, "Mitch Albom", "Tuesday with Morrie"),
            new Book(11, 2, "John Fowles", "Mag"), 
           };

    Shelf s = new Shelf(ks, 15);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

}

It is doesn't want to compile if the return statement is in the loop.

It will compile if I return in that way:

```
return book[0].toString+book[1].toString... etc....
```

But how to do it automatically?

--->I Updated all of the code of a class.

Comment: You don't, you return a string from toString.

Comment: So, you have array `book[]`, and you want to create a matching `String[]` array from it? Or, you want to join `book[]` array's items to produce a single `String` you can return for `toString` method? Or something else? Please clarify the question, because the code in it now doesn't make enough sense to know what you actually want!

Answer (score 1):

The `Arrays` utility class has a method to create a string from an array.

`return Arrays.toString(book);`

Comment: thanks, it works :) But this way gives me chars: "[" on the beginning and "]" on the end. Is it a way to delete this without using "\b"?

Comment: If you want to have a different format you need to write to code to make the string yourself.  Use a loop to iterate over the array and append each element to a `StringBuilder`

Comment: i dont know why, but it gives me a NullPointerException;/

Answer (score 0):

public **String** toString()

So you **must** return a String.

I suggest using A `StringBuilder` and Appending to it in your loop.

```
  public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0;i<book.length;i++)
    {
        sb.append(book[i].toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You are getting A NullPointerException Because of the way you initialize your Array

```
private Book book[] = new Book[20];
```

Change That to something like this:

```
   private Book book[] ;


public Shelf(Book[] ks, int j)
{
    book=new Book[ks.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ks.length ; i++)
    {


        this.book[i] = ks[i];

    }
}
```

Comment: bro provide proper example and explanation of it

Comment: it gives me NullPointerException ;/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling the method in a loop?
Then you need a parameter and you can use the method on every element of the array.

```
for (int i=0; i<book.length; i++) {

    toString(int i);

}
```

And the method:

```
public String toString(int i) {

    return book[i].toString();

}
```

Not nice, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This day and age, I would suggest something along these lines:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.stream(book).map(Book::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
```